# Using count.values and/or sort.values in Pandas DataFrames to sort number of values by each given category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my question is regarding the use of pandas and dataframes. So far, I have managed to re-name columns and drop all null values from dataset. The dataset consists of GDPR fines given by each quoted article and to each country and authority etc.

The head of the dataset after processing looks like this:

head of dataset after processing:
[image: head of dataset after processing]

With this code block, I also managed to sum given fines by each broken GDPR article accordingly:

```
article_and_date = gdpr_fines.groupby(["quoted article"]).sum()
article_and_date.sort_values(['fine'], ascending=[0], inplace=True)
article_and_date.head(10)
```

quoted articles vs. fine:
[image: quoted articles vs. fine]

My question being: How can I use count.values and/or sort.values functions to count what is the number of given fines per country? So not total sum, but individual number of given fines. Referring to earlier code block: How could I also count the number of fines vs. quoted article? Like top-10 sort out of most fined articles.

This is my tryout, but for some reason it lists all columns even though I'm only referring to "Country" and "fine" columns.

```
fine_by_country = gdpr_fines.groupby(["Country"]).count()
fine_by_country.sort_values(['fine'], ascending=[0], inplace=True)
fine_by_country.head(10)
```

Here is the picture of output:

[image: fines by country tryout]

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe, don't show images

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
fine_by_country = gdpr_fines["fine"].groupby(["Country"]).count()
```

This may not work in that gdpr_fines["fine"] will produce a series rather than a dataframe.  You may need to include a second colum to keep it a dataframe then drop the resulting counts.

Comment: Just ran a test and the .groupby().count() chain works on a series as well.  Nicolas Gervais makes a good point about using double brackets to keep it a dataframe, though.

Answer (score 0):

When you post on S/O, please keep it *minimal*. From what I understand in your 20+ lines, your only issue is keeping one column and ignore the rest. That's a simple [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) task. You can select only one column like this:

```
fine_by_country = fine_by_country.head(10)['fine']
```

If you really want to keep a DataFrame rather than a Series:

```py
fine_by_country = fine_by_country.head(10)[['fine']] # double brackets
```